# PayPal not receiving shipping cost: Validation error: PayPal amounts do not match (gross <N>). Order status changed from Pending Payment to On Hold

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, ups

I have Woocommerce, UPS shipping and USPS shipping plugin activated on site. Things work working perfectly before the latest update of plugins. I am using Woo 2.6.3 and its addons.

After the update PayPal is not able to receive the shipping cost for the order and hence it process only product total without shipping cost and on site we receive an error as:

> Validation error: PayPal amounts do not match (gross 2.75). Order status changed from Pending Payment to On Hold.

When I checked the log for PayPal in the request woocommerce does not add shipping cost under "payment_gross" and "mc_gross"

I have posted ticket for same to Woocommerce support but they will take too long to revert and as it's a live site I can't hold that much.

Comment: in latest woo they have introduced zone . that may be the reason , you may need to report it with shipping plugin team.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue except I'm using woocommerce's zones.  After hacking about and comparing latest to old working version of wc I noticed that the newer paypal gateway is now including the shipping cost under Shipping_1 in the paypal args where as before when it worked the shipping cost was included as an additional line item.  I realize this isn't an answer but perhaps this might spur someone else's mind in case there's an easy fix other than changing the code back... head banging on wall....

Comment: Did anyone manage to get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WooCommerce 2.6+ sends shipping costs as a ‘real’ shipping line item via PayPals API. 
If your PayPal account has shipping rules setup within it, these will take over and remove the cost WooCommerce sends across.
So You need to remove all the shipping rule set from your paypal account.

Check below link for more details:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/#my-shipping-costs-are-not-transferring-to-paypal